Batch Size and Fetch Size in Spring Boot JDBC client
I am exploring JDBC client of spring boot, and looking options to set batch size and fetch size.
But can not find any document/article explaining the same.
Is there a way preferbly in properties file to instruct spring boot to use it?

"Is there a way preferbly in properties file to instruct spring boot to use it?"
Short answer is NO.
Long answer you need to do it manually for each query you execute.
Also there is no universal way to do it. Solution will be different for different DB.

I am executing query like this - jdbcClient.sql("myQuery").param("someParam).query(new MyRowMapper()).optional();...where to set  batchsize and fetch size?

Inside myQuery.
